# Pytest - combining multiple fixture parameters into a single fixture to optimise fixture instantiation

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I have an existing `pytest` test that makes use of some predefined lists to test the cross-product of them all:

```
A_ITEMS = [1, 2, 3]
B_ITEMS = [4, 5, 6]
C_ITEMS = [7, 8, 9]
```

I also have an expensive fixture that has internal conditions dependent on A and B items (but not C), called F:

```
class Expensive:
    def __init__(self):
        # expensive set up
        time.sleep(10)
    def check(self, a, b, c):
        return True  # keep it simple, but in reality this depends on a, b and c

@pytest.fixture
def F():
    return Expensive()
```

Currently I have a naive approach that simply parametrizes a test function:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("A", A_ITEMS)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("B", B_ITEMS)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("C", C_ITEMS)
def test_each(F, A, B, C):
    assert F.check(A, B, C)
```

This tests all combinations of F with A, B and C items, however it constructs a new `Expensive` instance via the `F` fixture for *every* test. More specifically, *it reconstructs a new `Expensive` via fixture F* for every combination of A, B and C.

This is very inefficient, because I should only need to construct a new `Expensive` when the values of A and B change, which they don't between all tests of C.

What I would like to do is somehow combine the `F` fixture with the `A_ITEMS` and `B_ITEMS` lists, so that the F fixture only instantiates a new instance once for each run through the values of C.

My first approach involves separating the A and B lists into their own fixtures and combining them with the F fixture:

```
class Expensive:
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        # expensive set up
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        time.sleep(10)
    def check(self, c):
        return True  # keep it simple

@pytest.fixture(params=[1,2,3])
def A(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=[4,5,6])
def B(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def F(A, B):
    return Expensive(a, b)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("C", C_ITEMS)
def test_each2(F, C):
    assert F.check(C)
```

Although this tests all combinations, unfortunately this creates a new instance of `Expensive` for each test, rather than combining each A and B item into a single instance that can be reused for each value of C.

I've looked into indirect fixtures, but I can't see a way to send multiple lists (i.e. both the A and B items) to a single fixture.

Is there a better approach I can take with pytest? Essentially what I'm looking to do is minimise the number of times `Expensive` is instantiated, given that it's dependent on values of item A and B.

Note: I've tried to simplify this, however the real-life situation is that F represents creation of a new process, A and B are command-line parameters for this process, and C is simply a value passed to the process via a socket. Therefore I want to be able to send each value of C to this process without recreating it every time C changes, but obviously if A or B change, I need to restart it (as they are command-line parameters to the process).

Answer (score 0):

If using pytest scoping (as proposed in the other answer) is not an option, you may try to cache the expansive object, so that it will be constructed only if needed.

Basically, this expands the proposal given in the question with an additional static caching of the last used parameters to avoid creating a new `Expansive` if not needed:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=A_ITEMS)
def A(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=B_ITEMS)
def B(request):
    return request.param


class FFactory:
    lastAB = None
    lastF = None

    @classmethod
    def F(cls, A, B):
        if (A, B) != cls.lastAB:
            cls.lastAB = (A, B)
            cls.lastF = Expensive(A, B)
        return cls.lastF

@pytest.fixture
def F(A, B):
    return FFactory.F(A, B)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("C", C_ITEMS)
def test_each(F, C):
    assert F.check(C)
```

Comment: I like this approach - apart from the globals, but they can be managed - thank you.

Comment: I adapted the answer to remove the uglier version with the globals - I wouldn't have used that one, either.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success using a more broadly scoped fixture (module or session) as "cache" for the per-test fixture for this sort of situation where the "lifetimes" of the fixtures proper don't align cleanly with amortised costs or whatever.

Comment: The problem is that I need the lifetime of the top-level fixture to be for each distinct combination of A and B, which is multiple times per module or session, unfortunately. The combination expansion of A and B is too large to create a separate module for each one, unfortunately.

Comment: @davidA you can have the cache only hold one item (or a few), and cleanup the older ones as you go.